# Young Adult novel, young man fights with spear, becomes a gladiator at some point in a demon arena

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, demons

I read it sometime around 2010, it involved a young man, possibly a teenager that fought using a spear, and at some point the modern world was taken over by demons, and the nations of the world negotiated with the demons to survive. He fought as a gladiator in an arena filled with demons. It was part of a series, and for some reason I keep thinking of the spear of Cucuhlainn.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE Ian!  Feel free to take the [Science Fiction & Fantasy tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. This question seems very sparse on details, so you might want to consider visiting [How to ask a good question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) together with this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) and subsequently add more details to your question, so that it will be easier for others to find the book that you are searching for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is The Tapestry Series by Henry Neff.

[The Hound of Rowan](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/603515.The_Hound_of_Rowan?from_search=true) Bit "Harry Potter"-ish. With the set-up of the Rowan School and his adventures there.

[The Second Siege](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2475768.The_Second_Siege) Where the demons take over.

[The Fiend and the Forge](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6185409-the-fiend-and-the-forge) This one has the gladiator bits.

[The Maelstrom](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13531506-the-maelstrom)

[The Red Winter](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15829770-the-red-winter)

The main character, Max, is a throw-back hero with special powers.  Often called the Hound of Rowan, he is a spiritual Cu Chulain and does get a spear at some point (can't remember if it is Cu Chulain's).