# Trying to find name of fantasy book with characters possibly called Max and Daniel

Tags: story-identification, novel, mythology

This is my first time asking a question here so sorry if I mess up anything.

I've been trying to find the title of a fantasy book that I heard on Audio CD 5-10 years ago, so my memories of it may be wrong. What I remember is that the book was based off of some sort of European mythology, and the main character was called Max, and he was some sort of 'Chosen One' and his best friend was called Daniel who was really powerful. They are sent to some school. I also recall some kind of tapestry is involved. At the school I think there is some ogre cook who almost eats Daniel, because he misses the session where she meets them. I also believe each student got an animal, and Max had a fox looking animal? I also remember them going to some geothermal facility for some reason...

Sorry for the sparse details!

Comment: How long is "very very long"?  A decade, two decades?

Comment: I'm realizing 'very very long' is a really subjective term to use (apologies), and because I'm GenZ "long" for me is actually pretty short for most but I'd say between 5 and 10 years ago. It was long enough I can't really remember when.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might mean *[The Hound of Rowan](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/603515.The_Hound_of_Rowan)*, #1 of The Tapestry series.

If you do, Max doesn't have a friend called Daniel, the lead is called Max McDaniels. David is Max's friend.

[image: Book Cover - *The Hound of Rowan*]

> Max McDaniels lives a quiet life in the suburbs of Chicago, until the day he stumbles upon a mysterious Celtic tapestry. Many strange people are interested in Max and his tapestry. His discovery leads him to Rowan Academy, a secret school where great things await him.
>
> But dark things are waiting, too. When Max learns that priceless artworks and gifted children are disappearing, he finds himself in the crossfire of an ancient struggle between good and evil. To survive, he'll have to rely on a network of agents and mystics, the genius of his roommate, and the frightening power awakening within him.

Also, [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/50708867?book_show_action=true) indicates that the cook is a "Hag", not an ogre:

> Lots of wonderful touches--people keep mentioning "Mum" the reformed (well mostly)hag cook with good reason--she's wonderfully funny.

Comment: This series has come up a couple of times.  @royboy64 You might check out these questions/answers for additional details if you aren't convinced: [Question 1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162065/young-adult-novel-young-man-fights-with-spear-becomes-a-gladiator-at-some-poin); [Question 2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176113/boy-goes-to-magical-boarding-school); [Question 3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151780/ya-novel-series-involving-magical-student-warrior)